# How to move a pacman in an android application?

Tags: android, pacman

i have painted canvas for maze using two dimensional array.
now i want to know

1.how i can show pacman animated(in j2me we can fill the circles by some degrees)?

2.how the pacman moves and eat the food means when pacman moves the screen will be repainted?

thankx

Answer (score 1):

[Start by following the graphics tutorials here](http://androidwizard.net/category/intermediate-android-app-development/graphics-intermediate/).  Particularly the "Playing with Graphics" series.  If you have a **specific** problem, come here and ask it.  Otherwise, questions asking "How can I make a game where such-and-such happens and so-and-so is animated" are generally not welcome.

Comment: The snake sample is also a good starting point, which is included in the SDK samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [flixel-android](http://code.google.com/p/flixel-android/) lib (especially if you are familiar with ActionScript 3 programming model). It will take the heavy lifting out of animation loops and tweens calculation. So you don't need to mess around with third-party tweeners, loops with `Timer`s, `TimerTask`s and `ScheduledExecutorService`s.

Hope this will help you.